# Comparing data from same file in reducer function of a map reduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my map reduce program, the mapper function will give two key value pair:

1) (person1, age)

2) (person2, age)

(I have kept 2 pairs only for simplicity it would be nice if u can explain for n nos of line)

Now I want to write a reducer which will compare age of both and give the answer who is older.

The thing I cannot understand is the output of mapper will be in different line in the file. And as reducer works on line by line bases over a file how will it compare them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if any of the following logic serves your purpose:

A.

1. emit (age,person_name) from your map
2. have only 1 reducer - 
   your will get all ages, person pair in sorted manner. so simply emitting will give first one as youngest and last one as oldest.

   If you don't want to print all values, just have two references in the reducer task - youngest, oldest - set them in reduce method and emit whichever you want in the cleanup of reducer task

B.

1. Have a mapper emitting (name,age) as you said
2. in reducer task:

   a. Use setup() to create a treemap

   b. in reduce() add (age, person) in the treemap

   c. you map will be sorted by age which you can use in cleanup() to do something about it.

Essentially you can store all key,value in internal object(s) in reduce(), in cleanup() you will have access to all of these value and perform any logic you want in it.

Comment: That's Great!!!! I was looking for the functions, setup() and cleanup(), as u mentioned. Thank you

Comment: The clean up method is called once per task(for mapper or reducer). So for reducer, this is still at each key i suppose

Comment: @Ramzy, reducer task contains following methods in the order:

1. setup()

2. for each key,value reduce()

3. cleanup()



so reduce() will have only one key and its values but you don't have to emit them, just store them in internal data structure (hashmap, list).

 In cleanup() you have all the keys and values you stored in your internal object, where you can perform your logic.

Comment: Ok, assumiing this is for option B, then reducer task would have handled part of all the keys, unless its a single reducer. So can we go ahead with this, to compare all keys from all mapper outputs?

Comment: @Gaurav - what is the data set size you are operating? if data set size is large, I doubt the efficiency of single reducer.

Comment: @Ramzy, Single reducer is still required to have all the data in the cleanup(). Also as Ravindra mentioned these are not efficient solutions with very large data as reducer memory can be bottleneck.  I just wanted to point out how we can get rid of the limitation of knowing only  one key, values limation in recue(). This approach can be useful in scenarios where mapper are processing very large amount of data but reducer input is not very large (so single reducer is ok).

Comment: Sorry due to my tight schedule I have not yet tried this, but though K246 at present my data set is small, but yes in future my data set might be large also. So @Ramzy & K246 thank you for this good discussion, it gave a good insight to this topic to a naive hadoop developer like me. I will try both approach this one and secondary sort.

Answer (score 1):

I think your use case straight away fits into **Secondary Sorting** technique.

Secondary sorting is a technique, which has been introduced to sort "value" emitted by mapper. Primary sorting will be done by "key" emitted by mapper.

If you try to sort all values at reducer level, you may get out of memory. Secondary Sorting should be done at mapper level.

Have a look at this [article](http://codingjunkie.net/secondary-sort/)

**In above example, just replace "year" with "person" and "temperature" with "age"**

Solution:

1. Create Custom partitioner to send all values from a particular key to a single reducer
2. Sorting should be done Key, Value combination emitted by mapper => Create a composite key with Key + Value have been used for sorting. Come up with a  Comparator which sorts first by **Key** and then with **Value**.

Answer (score 0):

In reducer method, all you would be getting is a key and list of values. So you can find min or max among a list of values for that key.  However if you need to compare with other keys, then may be you should think of a single reducer and get all the records from mappers and handle that logic in your reducer class with help of reference variable rather than local variable and updating the reference variable with every min/max value for each key

Comment: You are right, if I have to compare values of same key it is easy, but in my case I want to compare value having different key. As u said I can use reference variable but issue in that is I cannot sort all values till I get all the values. So how would I know that this is the last call to reducer after this there is no data?

Comment: When you say you want only one reducer, then all the data from all the mappers would be available and you can perform the comparision. Set number of reducer tasks to 1, and it should take care.

Comment: There is one reducer only but mapper will give suppose n records having different keys. Now if I want to compare values associated with key 1 with the value associated with key 2 then how its that possible. Actually this is also possible, but for sorting all this n records how do I know which is the last record given by mapper.(Here by one record I mean a <key, values> pair forwarded by mapper)

Comment: once all the mappers are done, since you have only one reducer, then the reducer method will be called for each key. So number of time the reducer method is called is equal to number of keys. So you can check for all values for that key and get minimum, and keep a reference of instance variable and updated as the reducer method is called.

Comment: For minimum and maximum it is right that one reference variable will be enough. But if I need to do sorting on values having different key then?

Comment: Sorting is a different logic altogether. The single reduce option for max/min is defintely not a good design, because when you work with large files the performance would be a hit. Now I understand that you need two thinks, one is sorting and other is mi/max based on sorted data. So I see the option is **Secondar sort** where you can use parallelism of reducers and get your use case solved. But this requires a good coding effort where you have to think of composite key, cmoparator at partitioning and reducer grouping. You can lok at Hadoop Definitive Guide - Secondary sort for good information